# MySQL to find the number of employee(s) for each month

Tags: mysql, count, sqlcommand

[This is the table named employee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLPGk.png)

[This is the question and sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmuY4.png)

```
SELECT MONTH(EMP_HIREDDATE) AS “Hire Month”, COUNT(EMP_NUM) AS “No Of Employee” 
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY EMP_NUM;
```

The above command doesn't return the desired output.

I understand that COUNT(EMP_NUM) is not working because each employee is having a unique EMP_NUM but I've no idea what to do

Comment: Please don't use images. They are hard to read, and reproduce. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Just change your GROUP BY and set **GROUP BY MONTH(EMP_HIREDDATE)**

Comment: *"The above command doesn't return the desired output"* that query should have giving a error... Time to configure sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY if your MySQL version does support it..

Answer (score -1):

Use this (Just Change Group by Clause)

```
  SELECT MONTH(EMP_HIREDDATE) AS “Hire Month”, COUNT(EMP_NUM) AS “No Of Employee” FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY MONTH(EMP_HIREDDATE);
```